# foreach showing two results in just one column - Laravel 9.x / Livewire

Tags: laravel, foreach

When I trigger foreach to show the products registered in each process, separated by line and column, it returns the result all in just one line.

Sorry about my English

Example:

| ID | header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1525, 1523 | Item 1, Item 2 |

*what i want to show*

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1525 | Item 1 |
| 1523 | Item 2 |

***Back End:***
`

```
 public function viewLicitacao($id) {
        $licitacao = Licitacao::find($id); $this->showModalLicitacao();
        
        $this->licitacao_id_processo = $licitacao->id;
        $this->licitacao_destino = $licitacao->cliente_nome;
        $this->licitacao_date_entrega = $licitacao->date_entrega;
}
```

***Front End:***

```
@if($isModal == true)
  @foreach($licitacao as $processo)
  <div class="modal fade" id="ModalLicitacao">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Licitação - {{ $processo->id; }}</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h4>Informações das licitações</h4>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>N° do Processo: </label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" wire:model="licitacao_id_processo" placeholder="Informe o N° do processo" readonly/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="destino">Destinatário: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" wire:model="licitacao_destino" placeholder="Informe o nome do destinatário" readonly/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Data da entrega:</label>
                  <input type="text" wire:model="licitacao_date_entrega" class="form-control" placeholder="Data de entrega da mercadoria" readonly>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <h4>Produtos da licitação</h4>
          <div class="row">
            <table class="table table-hover text-nowrap">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Nome</th>
                  <th>Preço Unit</th>
                  <th>Quantidade</th>
                  <th>Qt. Disponivel</th>
                  <th>Ações</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
              <tbody>
                @forelse($processo->products as $key => $products)
                  <td>{{ $products->id_product }}</td>
                @empty
                  <td>Nenhum produto foi cadastrado nessa licitação</td>
                @endforelse
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
          <button type="submit" wire:click="closeModalLicitacao()" class="btn btn-default">Fechar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div>
  @endforeach
  <!-- /.modal -->
  @endif
```

The two tables have relationships

*Modal ProductLicitacao:*

```
class ProductLicitacao extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id_product', 'licitacao_id', 'name', 'qty', 'price_unit',
    ];
    
    
    public function licitacao()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Licitacao::class);
    }

}
```

*Modal Licitacao:*

```
class Licitacao extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'processo_number', 'cliente_nome', 'status', 'user_id', 'date_entrega', 'alert',
    ];
    protected $dates = [
        'date_entrega'
    ];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductLicitacao::class, 'licitacao_id');
    }

}
```

**Help me to solve this problem that seems to be simples, but it is being monstrous for my iniation in web development.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the tag `<tr>` before the `<td>`

```
<tbody>

    @forelse($processo->products as $key => $products)
        <tr>// <-- here
            <td>{{ $products->id_product }}</td>
            //other columns(td), you may have
        </tr>// <-- and here
    @empty
        <td>Nenhum produto foi cadastrado nessa licitação</td>
    @endforelse

</tbody>
```